# Finding out the port an asynchronous socket is binding to?

Tags: raku, asyncsocket

Since version 6.d of Perl 6, you can use port `0` to ask the interpreter to find a port to bind for you:

```
my $socket = IO::Socket::Async.listen($SOCKET_ADDR, 0);
```

However, $socket is a [`Supply`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Supply) with no information on the low-level socket it's using. What is the way of finding which port is it binding to?

Comment: Do you mean version 6.d?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you `tap` the `$socket` variable you get back a (*currently undocumented*) `IO::Socket::Async::ListenSocket` object. This has a couple of methods `socket-port` and `socket-host` which are `Promises` then when they resolve have the correct values.

We can probably tidy up the docs to indicate this.

Example :

```
my $s = IO::Socket::Async.listen("127.0.0.1",0);
my $t = $s.tap;
my $p = await $t.socket-port;
$p.say;
```